# Batch For /R Results to be set menu choice

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd

need a bit of help with a project.

Scenario :-

Manually migrating PC's to new Domain breaks a piece of software due to the new profile not having the settings from the old user profile - required to make it run. The old profile is called one thing, the new one -  something else e.g.

```
C:\Users\Sue.Barnes.B3209 (old) C:\Users\Susan.Barnes.NGP (new)
```

Within the %localappdata% of each (old) profile there "maybe" a config file for this software, if the user has used it previously. E.g.

```
C:\Users\Sue.Barnes.B3209\AppData\Local\Acme_Limited\Acme.exe_Url_m5l4ujc5t22f3qw0q5uz1dwlfcnrdaoh\1.0.0.15\user.config
```

Objectives :-

I want to be able to scan through the C:\Users Folder and report back the full path, name & extension of file where it is found, then have the list set in a menu choice where upon input choice will copy the user.config file to the exact same location but in the currently logged on new profile appdata folder.

e.g.

```
Enumerating List Of User Profiles in the System...

Admin
Public
User

From the Profiles detecting active Configs...

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Acme_Limited\Acme.exe_Url_m5l4ujc5t22f3qw0q5uz1dwlfcnrdaoh\1.0.0.15\user.config
C:\Users\Public\AppData\Local\Acme_Limited\Acme.exe_Url_m5l4ujc5t22f3qw0q5uz1dwlfcnrdaoh\1.0.0.15\user.config

Press any key to continue . . .
```

However it is at this point I'm out of my depth. I cant seem to be able to create a choices menu of each instance where the file is found. However many are found, I'd like a number to be printed on the screen so I can choose the correct config to copy to the newly set up profile. Simply,

```
    Xcopy /f C:\Users\Sue.Barnes.B3209\AppData\Local\Acme_Limited\Acme.exe_Url_m5l4ujc5t22f3qw0q5uz1dwlfcnrdaoh\1.0.0.15\user.config

%localappdata%\Acme_Limited\Acme.exe_Url_m5l4ujc5t22f3qw0q5uz1dwlfcnrdaoh\1.0.0.15\
```

Current code base :-

```
echo.
echo Enumerating List Of User Profiles in the System...
echo.
TIMEOUT /T 3 >NUL
dir /b C:\Users
echo.
echo From the Profiles detecting active Configs...
echo.
TIMEOUT /T 3 >NUL
for /R "C:\Users" %%a in (1.0.0.15\user.config*) do (
echo %%~dpnxa 
    )
)
echo.
pause
```

Any help be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: what's the upper limit of config files you expect to be returned?

Comment: No more than 10, ... Thanks

Comment: It seems to me as if this task may be better resolved, by using a base text file, which should hold individual lines, each containing the old and new user names as key pairs, perhaps, for example, `Sue.Barnes.B3209:Susan.Barnes.NGP`. There should be no need for interaction, like a menu system, just recurse the directory trees of each old user name, obtain the full user.config paths, and perform the file transfer, by replacing the user name with the matching paired new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
set "dontshow=u:\dontshow.txt"
set "configs=u:\configs.txt"
set "profiles=u:\profiles.txt"

:again

echo :>>"%dontshow%"
del "%configs%" >nul 2>nul
del "%profiles%" >nul 2>nul

:: Find all of the "user.config" files having ..\appdata\local\Acme_limited\...1.0.0.15
FOR /f "tokens=1-9delims=\" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\user.config" '
 ) DO if /i "%%d"=="appdata" if /i "%%e"=="local" if /i "%%f"=="Acme_Limited" if /i "%%h"=="1.0.0.15" (
 rem these are the users' config files that may be copied.
 echo %%c|findstr /x /g:"%dontshow%" /i /L >nul
 if errorlevel 1 >>"%configs%" echo %%c
)

:: Find all of the user profiles that are not in "dontshow" and do NOT have "user.config" - These are the profiles that may need to be processed
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%" '
 ) DO (
 echo %%a|findstr /x /g:"%dontshow%" /i /L >nul
 if errorlevel 1  echo %%a|findstr /x /g:"%configs%" /i /L >nul 
 if errorlevel 1 >>"%profiles%" echo %%a
)

:: Now we have a list of profiles with "user.config" missing in %profiles%
:: And possible source-profiles in %configs%

:: Show the list of "config missing" profiles
cls
findstr /n /v /L /c:":" "%profiles%"
:reselectd
set "selectiond="
set /p "selectiond=Choose destination profile "
if not defined selectiond goto :eof
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /v /L /c:":" "%profiles%"') do if "%%a"=="%selectiond%" set "selectiond=%%b"&goto selects
echo Invalid selection
goto reselectd

:selects

for /L %%a in (1,1,4) do echo.
findstr /n /v /L /c:":" "%configs%"

:reselects
set "selections="
set /p "selections=Choose source profile "
if not defined selections goto :eof
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n /v /L /c:":" "%configs%"') do if "%%a"=="%selections%" set "selections=%%b"&goto process
echo Invalid selection
goto reselects

:process
echo Copy from profile "%selections%" to "%selectiond%" ?
choice 

if errorlevel 2 goto again

:: Do the copy... just echoed, remove `echo` keyword to activate

ECHO md "%sourcedir%\%selectiond%\appdata\localAcme_Limited\whatever\1.0.0.15"
ECHO copy  "%sourcedir%\%selections%\appdata\localAcme_Limited\whatever\1.0.0.15\user.config" "%sourcedir%\%selectiond%\appdata\localAcme_Limited\whatever\1.0.0.15"
 
choice /M "Add '%selections%' to processed file ? "
if errorlevel 2 goto processedd

>>"%dontshow%" echo %selections%

:processedd
choice /M "Add '%selectiond%' to processed file ? "
if errorlevel 2 goto again

>>"%dontshow%" echo %selectiond%
goto again
```

Interesting exercise. Lack of information about what `Acme.exe_Url_m5l4ujc5t22f3qw0q5uz1dwlfcnrdaoh` is about (constant string, change-per-user? What?), though - left as an exercise for OP to resolve.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I decided that the key part is the third directory level - the user-id. This approach uses files of user-id, two are temporary and one is permanent - "dontshow.txt" which contains a list of user-ids NOT to show. This can be manually maintained using an editor if required.

So - to start, add a line containing a single colon to the "dontshow" file. This is a dummy which can never match a real user-id and is required because `findstr` doesn't like an empty dictionary file.

The first step is to find all of the `user.config` files, and use `for /f` to process the filenames found, selecting the significant directory-levels. Having excluded any path that does not fit the criteria, the third level contents is matched against the exclusions in "dontshow.txt". If the name found is new, add it to the `configs` file.

Second verse - same as the first, but this time only looking at the directory names. Note that the entry is made to `profiles` if the name found is NOT on the `dontshow` list AND is also NOT on the `config` list.

Now select a destination profile by listing `profiles` and appending a prefix `linenumber:` using `findstr`. Enter a number (manual entry, unchecked) and then match the line number by using `for/f`.

Rinse and repeat for the `configs` file for the source profile.

Display the proposed command, accept a Y/N response then ask whether each name should be added to the `dontshow` list.

And straight on 'til morning.

Note that responding with <kbd>Return</kbd> to any of the `set /p` commands will exit the batch.

Comment: That's superb! Tweaked the bits for me and does the job - with bells and whistles! Thanks Magoo!